# Solving an equation involving binomial coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> If $\displaystyle{22\choose0}{15\choose10}+{22\choose1}{15\choose9}+{22\choose2}{15\choose8}+\cdots+{22\choose9}{15\choose1}+{22\choose10}{15\choose0}={a\choose b}$, compute all possible values of $a+b$ where $a>b>0, b \neq 1$.

I tried writing it using $${n \choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$ and seeing if anything would cancel, but the work got messy. I can't think of any identities that can be applied here either.

What identities or manipulations can be applied to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: This is $\binom{37}{10}$. Imagine there are 37 balls - 22 are blue and 15 are red. What are the cases when you choose 10 balls?

Comment: The last part of the question is a but misleading, because there is a unique solution for $a$ and $b$ - Hint think of the hypergeometric distribution for choosing 10 items from 37 when 22 items are of type A and 15 are of type B

Comment: @HwChu Amazing! You should post this as an answer :)

Comment: The problem is not nearly as trivial as some seem to think, and not just because $\binom{37}{10}=\binom{37}{27}$. It's also not sufficient to exclude $b=1$, because $b=a-1$ gives the same. And there are quite a few other equal binomial coefficients, among them even one infinite family. Whether that are all possibilities, is an open problem, see [this article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.192.2826&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: @silverpegasus258 Is my answer correct? I would also like to know if there are any more forms of the same number that I answered.

Comment: @Manthanein I think your last binomial coefficient is wrong. It should be $348330136 \choose 348330135$?

Comment: @silverpegasus258 Yep I got it corrected. Anything else remaining?

Comment: @Manthanein No there aren’t. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example of Vandermonde's identity.

The given expression can be written as $$\sum_{i=0}^{10}\binom {22}{i} \binom {15}{10-i}$$
Hence by using Vandermonde's identity we get 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{10}\binom {22}{i} \binom {15}{10-i}$$
$$=\binom {37}{10}$$ 
$$= \binom {37}{27}$$
$$= \binom {348330136}{348330135} $$

You can visit

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Combinatorial_identity

For more information on Vandermonde's identity.

Comment: Uniqueness? Why can’t there be other solutions?

Comment: @Nemo Well there are. $\binom {37}{10}=\binom {37}{27}$ And there may or may not exist a solution equivalent to this expression of the form $\binom {a}{1}$. I leave the rest of the part for the OP because he just needed the hint to solve such expression. This site is note meant to provide step by step solution until the end to the question but is meant to spread the knowledge and power of mathematics.